# How to make sequential if statements asynchronous in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a series of if statements in a loop like this:

```
for( var i = 0; i < results_list.length; i++){
find = await results_list[i];    
    //result 1
    if (find.Process == "one") {
        await stored_proc(38, find.Num, find.Status)
    }
    //result 2
    if(find.Process == "two") {
        await stored_proc(37, find.Num, find.Status)
    }
    //result 3
    if(find.Process == "three") {
        await stored_proc(39, find.Num, find.Status)
    }
}
```

My issue is that it runs all of these synchronously causing my stored procedure to trip over itself. How can I ensure each `if` statement waits for the previous one to complete before running?

It is also important to know that each `if` statement is not always run, for instance on one run of my code `//result 2` may run and `//result 1` and `//result 3` may not run.

Sometimes they might all run and sometimes none will run at all.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** Here is my stored procedure function

```
async function stored_proc(opID, num, stat){
         sql.executeTransaction( connection, {
            procedure: "<stored procedure>",
            params: { 
                OpID: {
                    val: opID,
                    type: sql.INT
                },
                num: {
                    val: num,
                    type: sql.STRING
                },
                Pass: {
                    val: stat,
                    type: sql.INT
                },
                ExtraData: {
                    val: "upload",
                    type: sql.STRING
                }
            }
        } ).then( async function( data ) {
            return data.transaction
                .commit()
                .then( async function() {
                    console.log("Updated database...." );
                } );
        }, function( err ) {
            console.log( err );
        } );
    }
```

**SECOND EDIT:** I have looked into this some more and found that the if there is more than one result to upload it will **NEVER** upload the first sets of results. I have ran some `console.log()`s through and found it will always get `find.Num` and `find.Status`. It will only log `Updated database` for every result after the first one. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Put that code within an async function.

Comment: @Ele ah sorry, I skipped that part when writing the question. In my code it is in an async function

Comment: WRT the title - don't you mean make them *synchronous*? They seem to already by asynchronous, so making them "more asynchronous" seems a bit strange.

Comment: @VLAZ perhaps I wasn't clear, if I run this code it will not wait for each if statement to close it will run them all at the same time.

Comment: @VLAZ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835536/why-does-this-stored-procedure-not-upload-all-of-the-data-i-input I asked this question however have since narrowed down the answer it elaborates on my overall problem

Comment: First of all, you are trying to make it wait for asynchronous operations, you will never make them really synchronous. The await keyword will only make the code look synchronous. Second of all, your calling function from your linked question is not marked as `async`, that's likely your problem

Comment: But then you say that it doesn't wait for them, since you want them to run to completion before the next one, no? Or did I misunderstand. As I said, seems strange to want them async then describe synchronous behaviour.

Comment: Your code should run properly https://codesandbox.io/embed/immutable-grass-hl53l

Comment: The code you posted works. If it doesn't wait for the stored procedure results, it's the fault of the `stored_proc` function not returning a promise that fulfills at the right time.

Comment: Assuming `stored_proc` is an asynchronous function (hence the `await`), and you want to run them all in sequence, then this code should work fine. Have you tried stepping through the code to see if it really does run in sequence?

Comment: @EcSync I see. Then check AritraChakraborty's answer

Comment: @Bergi i have edited my question some after investigating the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `stored_proc` you are not returning the Promise.
Also, promise inside promise is considered anti-pattern you can chain it easily.

```
async function stored_proc(opID, num, stat) {
    return sql.executeTransaction(connection, {
        procedure: "<stored procedure>",
        params: {
            OpID: {
                val: opID,
                type: sql.INT
            },
            num: {
                val: num,
                type: sql.STRING
            },
            Pass: {
                val: stat,
                type: sql.INT
            },
            ExtraData: {
                val: "upload",
                type: sql.STRING
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.transaction
            .commit()
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log("Updated database....");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: I'd go further and convert the inner function to `await`s over `.then()`s too, but your answer is correct :)

Comment: Thanks for the response however it still doesn't work, it still doesn't upload the first result it finds to the database.